# Building treeView primefaces from XML file

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces, treeview

I try to generate a tree view from XML file dynamically, but I have issues with some problem like `@Postconstruct` and the navigation client jsf side.

**Below the part of index.xhtml page :**

problem 1 :
On this page I use a `UploadedFile button` to to choose the path, I get a problem because I can't get the full path for security reason.

```
            <p:fileUpload id="fu1" skinSimple="true"
                          value="#{dfView.file1}"
                          auto="true"
                          listener="#{dfView.handleFileUpload}"
                          update="msgs"
            />
```

problem 2 :
i got a problem with function `init()` and `@PostConstruct`

```
   <p:commandButton value=" generate tree " icon="pi pi-bookmark" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();"
                                 actionListener="#{dfInit.init}" Style="position: center"/>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" header="XML CONTENT" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="blind" >
    <h:form id="form2" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <p:layout style="min-width:900px;min-height:700px;">
            <p:layoutUnit header="GENEREATED XML FILE" position="west" resizable="true" size="50%" >
                <p:tree value="#{dfInit.root}" var="node" style="min-width: max-content" dynamic="true">
                    <p:treeNode>
                        <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
                    </p:treeNode>
                </p:tree>
            </p:layoutUnit>
         </p:layout>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

**xmlToTreeview.java :**

problem 3 : the tree-view is not initialized and i can't get attributes values

```
...
@Named("dfInit")
@ViewScoped
public class xmlToTreeview implements Serializable {

...
    static TreeNode root;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);
        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = docBuilder.
                parse(new File(ComparatorBean.getGeneratedPath()));

        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                // do something with the current element
                TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode("[ ELEM " + node1.getNodeName(), root);
                System.out.println(node1.getNodeName() +" : "+ node1.getTextContent() );
            }
        }
    }
```

**Expected output from XML :**

*Original XML file :*

```
<rootXML>
    <AAA id="0001">
        <BBB>text</BBB>
        <CCC/>
        <DDD id="xyz">
            value_of_ddd1
        </DDD>
    </AAA>
</rootXML>
```

*Expanded treeview :*

```
ROOT : "rootXML"
-ELEM AAA {ATT id=001}
   -ELEM BBB = "text"
   -ELEM CCC = null  
   -ELEM DDD
      -ELEM DDD1 : "value_of_ddd1" {ATT id="xyz"}
...
```

Thank you an advance.

Comment: Sorry, can't see @PostConstruct code (it isn't invoked?), does that class have the right annotation or configuration to trigger it? Can't understand problem 1, can you explain with an example? Problem 3 seems related to 2, right?

Comment: I use the same code in primefaces site with static model, for the part 2 of your qst - yes prb 3 is related to prb2

Comment: Why using @PostConstruct if you've a commandButton that do the same? Do you have a default file, loaded on page load? Is your actionListener defined as above?

Comment: No, i haven't a default file, yes actionListener defined as above